# nmcli shows nothing

Tags: ubuntu, nmcli

I have a strange scenario over here:
If I run `nmcli dev wifi list` it shows me a list of all networks which is fine. As soon as I add the device (wlan0 in my case) to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and reboot it shows no networks.

So before reboot the `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

```
#iface wlan0 inet manual
#  wpa-driver wext
#  wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# wpa_supplicant.conf contains no networks at the moment

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
# this directory is empty, so currently it is a redundant statement
```

I remove the first three `#`, reboot the device and nmcli shows no networks. How do I address this issue? I need the `wpa_supplicant.conf` empty because it will be filled by a script. Said script displays a list of networks (via `nmcli`) and generates a wpa_supplicant.conf (via `wpa_passphrase`)

I'm aware there is a similar question [over there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158328/network-manager-not-listing-wifi), but the only answer to start the `wpa_supplicant.service` won't fix my issue, as the service is already running (according to `# systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service`). Restarting it does not change anything either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is normal. The NetworkManager don't manages devices in `/etc/network/interfaces` by default. You can change it in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` key `[ifupdown]
managed=true`

Comment: Just tried it, it was exactly the solution to my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that on recent Ubuntu versions (which ones?) there is a thing called Netplan who do not talk with NetworkManager as default and that could also be the cause of similar errors.

In that case, as fix:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml.bak

sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-activate-networkmanager.yaml
```

And in the file write this content:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
# Set and change netplan renderer to NetworkManager GUI tool
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Then since I don't have much knowledge about Netplan I just suggest a reboot and `nmcli` should then be OK.