# Unable to connect to WiFi

Tags: networking, fedora, wifi, nmcli

### Set-up

I'm using Fedora 31 on a notebook without any display attached. (I got this notebook for free, because the display was broken and I still use it as a server for various tasks).

Furthermore, I'm using a wifi USB dongle because I accidentally cut through the onboard wifi antenna. If I need to get work done, I connect using ssh or vnc.

### Description

After upgrading from Fedora 30 to 31 I noticed that after a while I wasn't able to connect via ssh anymore. I figured this might be related to power/energy settings.

So, I connected with vnc and toggled the following setting:
[image]

At this point, I got disconnected immediately and I haven't been able to connect properly every since.

At first, I attached a display of mine, but after the Fedora bootscreen, no desktop was shown. As a result I plugged my Ethernet cable in and wanted to check what was wrong by means of `xrandr`. However, this command only returned `Can't open display`.

I then went ahead and tried reactivating my WiFi by means of `nmcli` and discovered the following:

- After the boot, I have to execute `sudo rfkill unblock wifi`
- Afterwards, I need to activate it via `sudo ifconfig <wifi> up`
- Now, `sudo iwlist <wifi> scan` shows my SSID again. (nmcli dev wifi list is empty though…)
- `nmcli connection up id <SSID>` returns `Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device <wifi> not available because device is not available)`

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158328/network-manager-not-listing-wifi) describes my problem, but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: Some notebooks have hardware switch for wifi. Check if by accident you switch it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I haven't accidentally switched it.